# Not able to get current state value in function in "React.js"

Tags: reactjs

```
export class FruitShopPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          getFruitCode: ''
        }
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle() {
        alert("Get Updated value of data::",this.state.getFruitCode);
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
            {
                Header: 'Sr.No',
                id: "row",
                maxWidth: 50,
                Cell: (row) => {
                    return <div>{row.index + 1}</div>
                }
            },
            {
                Header: 'Fruit Code',
                accessor: 'fruitCode'
            }
        ];

        const onRowClick = (state, rowInfo, column, instance) => {
            return {
                onClick: e => {
                    let fruitCodeValue = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(rowInfo.original)).fruitCode;
                    this.setState({
                        getFruitCode: fruitCodeValue,

                    });
                  }
                }
            }
            return (
                <div>
                    <Button onClick={this.toggle}>Fruit Shop</Button>
                    <Modal isOpen={this.state.collapse} size="lg">
                        <ModalHeader>Fruit shop</ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
                            <div className="form-group">
                                <div>
                                    <ReactTable
                                        data={this.state.listFruitsData}
                                        columns={columns}
                                        defaultPageSize={10}
                                        getTrProps={onRowClick}
                                    />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <Row>
                                            <Button type="submit" onClick= 
                                             {this.toggle}>Buy</Button>

                                    </Row>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ModalBody>
                    </Modal>
                </div>
            )
      }
}
```

In above code I wanted to access updated value of getFruitCode(which is present in state) in function toggle(which I am displaying using alert)

scenario:

1. I am using React Table where I am populating data from post
   request
2. When I click on any row of table I am getting specific row data
   (as we are using  getTrProps={onRowClick} )
3. Also I am updating state value of getFruitCode in onRowClick by
   using setState
4. Now I wanted to access this updated state value of
   getFruitCode(current row value not previous value) in toggle method
5. I am getting blank variable in toggle method
6. how can I get updated current variable(getFruitCode) of state in
   toggle method?

Comment: are you getting data in fruitCodeValue ? do console.log and tell us what you are getting in console.log(fruitCodeValue) before this.setState({
                        getFruitCode: fruitCodeValue,

                    });

Comment: Yes I am getting value of fruitcodeValue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is already working. Just you write wrong code for `alert`.

```
alert(`Get Updated value of data: ${this.state.getFruitCode}`)
```

That's it.

Comment: But what if I have to print it in console.log(this.state.getFruitCode) it does not print value

Comment: Definitely this will work in console as well. This is the small demo link for you. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-61rtfq

Answer (score 1):

alert function has only one parameter, so just change your code as follow

```
alert("Get Updated value of data::" + this.state.getFruitCode)
```

and if state is set it should work fine